# How to change the color of AppBar button text

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, appbar

I have an `AppBar Button` that I want to change the color of the text.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"  Foreground="White"/>
```

I can change the button color by `Foreground="White"` but that does not change the text color so how can I change the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify `AppBarButtonStyle` slightly. Currently the `Foreground` of text is default set as `AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush`, but you can replace with `TemplateBinding` of `Foreground`. So use the below given style, so when will you set `Foreground` it will change foreground of button as well as the text below it.

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="App Bar Button"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Width="100" Background="Transparent">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,12,0,11">
                        <Grid Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="53.333" Margin="-4,-19,0,0" Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="OutlineGlyph" Text="&#xE0A7;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="53.333" Margin="-4,-19,0,0"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-1,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="TextLabel"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding AutomationProperties.Name}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Margin="0,0,2,0"
                            FontSize="12"
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            Width="88"
                            MaxHeight="32"
                            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                            Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                    <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundCheckedGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Strange that they would make it so that only the button and not the text too

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting the theme brush worked for me.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White"/>
```